# How to partition a string into two groups using a regex?

Tags: regex, string, rust

I'd like to partition a string into two groups by providing the regex for only one group in Rust.

The regex for the opposite group is not known. I only know the regex for the separator.

For example, with the regex `\d+` and the following string

```
123abcdef456ghj789
```

I'd like to obtain both these two strings

```
abcdefghj
```

and

```
123456789
```

Using the `regex` and `itertools` crates, I'm able to get the first group like this

```rs
let text = "123abcdef456ghj789";

let re = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();

let text1 = re.split(text).join(""); //abcdefghj
```

How can I get the second group?

Comment: Is the characters you are trying to match always `\d+`? if so, you may not need to use regex.

Comment: No, the example is very simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired result very similarly:

```
re.find_iter(text).map(|m| m.as_str()).join("");
```

[`.find_iter()`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find_iter) returns all matches as an iterator, which you can then call [`.as_str()`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Match.html#method.as_str) on get the full matched text. And then of course use `.join()` from itertools as you've done before.

Full example on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0607c80d68923a95d6264c682768d421).

---

> It would be nice though if there was a single method that returned a tuple of the disjoined partitions.

It would be nice and certainly possible since the matches return all the information needed to slice-and-dice the text in one pass. Here's my attempt that iteratively calls [`.find_at()`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find_at):

```
fn partition_regex(re: &Regex, text: &str) -> (String, String) {
    let mut a = String::new();
    let mut b = String::new();

    let mut search_idx = 0;
    while let Some(m) = re.find_at(text, search_idx) {
        a.push_str(m.as_str());
        b.push_str(&text[search_idx..m.start()]);
        search_idx = m.end();
    }
    b.push_str(&text[search_idx..]);
    
    (a, b)
}
```

Full example on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8995e80abf3bf589fa0d6559be4a9427).

Comment: Thanks, that works. It would be nice though if there was a single method that returned a tuple of the disjoined partitions. Maybe someday...

Comment: @mdcq I expanded the answer with code that does this in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [partition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) to create two sets based on a predicate.

```rust
let re = Regex::new(r"(^[a-z]+)").unwrap();

let (matches, non_matches): (String, String) 
    = content.lines().partition(|x| re.is_match(x));
```

Comment: Whoops, this was a solution for before your edit.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that in the special case of lines the partitioning is available. For this reason the revised example uses a single line to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more extensive but w/o an external library:

```
let re = regex::Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
let mut text1 = String::new();
let mut text2 = String::new();
let mut beg = 0;
let txt = "123abcdef456ghj789";
for r in re.find_iter(txt).map(|m| m.range()) {
    text1 += &txt[r.clone()];
    text2 += &txt[beg..r.start];
    beg = r.end;
}
text2 += &txt[beg..];
println!("{text1}\n{text2}");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=d157139d60fac2216110551f0923216b)